# Fatal error: Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::execute() on line 30 (SQLyog)

Tags: php

I currently working on dashboard using PHP. I need to fetch data from database inside SQLyog, and transfer it into a graph. The problem is I keep getting this error; Fatal error: Call to undefined method MDB2_Error::execute() on line 30 in the class coding. The error is on `$res = $query->execute($data);` Can someone help me with my coding?

Here is the code for class.

```
<?php
class fetch_ranking extends MDB2{
    var $con;
    var $tbl_user;
    var $tbl_isi_scopus_webo;

    function fetch_ranking ($dsn) {
        $this->con =& MDB2::singleton($dsn, $options=null);
        //echo $this->con->getMessage();
        if (PEAR::isError($this->con)) {
            die($this->con->getMessage());
        }

        $this->tbl_user = 'user';
        $this->tbl_isi_scopus_webo = 'ISI_SCOPUS_WEBO';
    }

    function fetch_webojuly16(){

        $types = array();
        $sql = "select university, criteria_rank as presence
                from isi_scopus_webo
                where month='july'
                and year='2016'
                group by university" ;   

        $query = $this->con->prepare($sql,$types,MDB2_PREPARE_RESULT);
        $data = array();
        $res = $query->execute($data);

       if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
           die($res->getMessage());          
        }

        $this->con->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
        $valrec = $res->fetchAll();
        return $valrec;
  }
}?>
```

And this is for the graph.

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/siteconf.php');
require_once($basehome.'/config/default.php');
require_once($basedir.'/mod/ppsg/dsn.php');
require_once($basehome.'/mod/ppsg/class/fetch_data_from_db_isi_scopus_webo.php');

$current_year = date('Y', strtotime(date('Y')));

//$fhObj = new fetch_ranking($ranking);

$hostname="192.168.111.55";
$username="devopt";
$password="G0devopt$";
$dbname="ranking";


//Connect to the database
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";


mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection)
  or die("Could not select examples");

$xdata=array();
$ydata=array();

$xdata['name'] = 'PRESENCE';
$ydata['name'] = 'UNIVERSITY';

$ydata['color'] = '#ABEBC6';

//Call to a member function fetch_webojuly16() on a non-object
$webojuly16 = $fhObj->fetch_webojuly16();

foreach($webojuly16 as $wj16){
    $xdata['data'][] = $wj16['presence'];
    $ydata['data'][] = $wj16['university'];
}

$json_arr = array($xdata,$ydata);
print json_encode($json_arr, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

?>
```

[This is the coding for graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T353.jpg)

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: line 35. on the graph code

Comment: You should paste all code here rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: Where do you initialize `$fhObj`?

Comment: Now that i initialized $fhObj, there's another error :(

Comment: you should post a new question

Comment: Which line causes the error? I cannot count to 30.

Comment: Its on `if (PEAR::isError($res))`

Answer (score 0):

The `$this->con->prepare($sql,$types,MDB2_PREPARE_RESULT);` call might return a `MDB2_Error` object in case the `prepare()` statement fails, as documented on http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2/docs/latest/MDB2/MDB2_Driver_Common.html#methodprepare. You have to check with `PEAR::isError` if that is the case or not. In your case it is, so you cannot call `$res = $query->execute($data);` on a `MDB2_Error` object, and that's exactly what the error message is telling you.

Add the if statement to check for errors on the `$query` variable and check the error messages you get.